# Singleton as Interface for testability via dependancy injection

Tags: c++, interfaces, dependency-injection, singleton, abstract-class

It can be found in many advices on topic that having `Singleton`s is an anti-pattern. Especially for cases of testability. Can someone please advice/critique on this way (please see code below) of dealing with this kind issue.

Also please kindly confirm/correct that the presented way of passing a reference to `ISingleton` in `SingletonUser` ctor reflects notion of what is called `dependancy injection`.

```
#include <iostream>

class ISingleton
{
public:
    virtual void doOp() = 0;
    virtual ~ISingleton() = default;
};



class Singleton : public ISingleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& get()
    {
        static Singleton s;
        return s;
    }

    void doOp() override
    {
        get().doOpImpl();
    }

private:
    void doOpImpl()
    {
        std::cerr << "Singleton: " << __func__ << '\n';
    }

private:
    Singleton() = default;

    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;

};


class SingletonUser
{
public:
    SingletonUser(ISingleton& i = Singleton::get()) : i_{i}
    {}

    void operator()()
    {
        i_.doOp();
    }

private:
    ISingleton& i_;

};

class SingletonMock : public ISingleton
{
public:
    void doOp() override
    {
        std::cerr << "SingletonMock: " << __func__ << '\n';
    }
};


int main()
{
    SingletonUser su;
    su();

    SingletonMock sm;
    SingletonUser s_user_mocked{sm};
    s_user_mocked();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave the Singleton discussion aside for now and focus on testability and dependency injection.

This is a type of dependency injection and it achieves *some* of the goals. You can easily inject a faked `ISingleton` to your `SingletonUser`, which takes care of the testability concerns. However, you have an awkward dependency graph with `SingletonUser` being dependent on both `ISingleton` and `Singleton`. In some cases this is fine, in some cases (usually larger projects) it is not. For example, I'm not well-versed enough in C++ compilers to say for sure, but I suspect this will lead to more recompilation as your `Singleton` and `SingletonUser` are "unnecessarily" linked. It will be harder for you to separate these classes if you ever need to, in the future. But a "perfect" dependency graph is not the only concern - sometimes the tradeoff for extra immediate convenience is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The Singleton design pattern gives the message "There can only ever be one instance of this class in the system." Even though you have done a good attempt at dependency injection, by implementing the Singleton pattern, you giving developers the message that it is also acceptable to call `Singleton::get()` themselves when they need access to that object, even if it also is already passed as a dependency in the constructor.

Because, if there is only ever one instance, `Singleton::get()` and `i_` are just two ways to access the same thing.

To avoid the bugs that can be caused by such (faulty) reasoning, you really should make a choice. Either use the Singleton pattern, and do all access through `Singleton::get()`, or use dependency injection. But do not try to mix them for the same class.

In the large majority of cases, the statement "there can only ever be one" is incorrect anyway, so the Singleton pattern is the wrong choice. The fact that you currently have only one instance is *not* an indication to use the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was Michael Feathers who in his book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" recommended to add a method to the singleton class which allows for setting (and thus replacing) the actual instance of the singleton. Take care to name the method appropriately like `ReplaceInstanceForTesting`in order to prevent others from using it in production code.

That is, you'd still need the interface, the "normal" implementation, and some mock implementation(s).